# Finding the place to put .txt files in Python to open - using Ubuntu 15

Tags: python

I'm really new to programming and I've been getting on with Python3 and please with my progress even if I'm all set up a little wonky still.

The tutorial that I am working on requests me to perform

```
my_file = open(welcome.txt)
```

but when I press enter I get this...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    my_file = open(welcome.txt)
NameError: name 'welcome' is not defined
```

I read on another forum that the file needed to be in the same location as where python executes from, but I have no idea where to find the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 issues:

1) The file name needs to be a string, so enclose it with quotes, like so:
`my_file = open('welcome.txt')`

2) The file needs to be either in the same directory, or you need to specify where it is, like:
`my_file = open('/home/user/welcome.txt')`

Comment: But how do I find the same directory so it can be placed there, that is what I am ultimately looking to do.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that? If so, place this in your code and you should see where this is: `import os
print os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))`

Comment: Probably not then, but I have to say, finding information on this subject has not been easy. I've been left feeling a little disheartened when it comes to sorting this out.

Answer (score 0):

File name should be in quotes:

```
my_file = open("welcome.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you forgot to enclose the file name in quotes:

```
my_file = open("welcome.txt")
```

The `open` function requires the file name as string as positional argument. What you did was to tell Python to use the value of the property `txt` of the variable `welcome`, which doesn't exist.